# Why can't typescript infer the generic type of a conditional properly?

Tags: typescript

Here's my problem:

```
export type ForEachList<T> =
    T extends Element ? (NodeListOf<T> | HTMLCollectionOf<T>) :
    T extends CSSRule ? CSSRuleList :
    T extends Attr ? NamedNodeMap :
    T extends Node ? (Node[] | NodeList) :
    T[];

export function forEach<T>(array: ForEachList<T>,
                        forEachFn: (value: T, index: number, arr: ForEachList<T>, done: () => void) => boolean | void,
                        thisArg?: any): void { 
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const foo = array[i];
        forEachFn.call(thisArg, foo, i, array, () => { /* empty on purpose */ });
//                              ^^^ error here
    }
}
```

```
Argument of type 'Node | CSSRule | T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Node | CSSRule | T'.
    Type 'Node' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Node'.(2345
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBi0CiBDAxgCwBkBLAZxgB4AVAPjgF4BYAKDjbirlBmADsATUnEwAbYAFs+8APxwAFADkI-YCXIB5AGbU6AHzgAJKgFlCAYQgixuGMQi8tOgJRwAXC3YcuIHgKFmAZQCAJQBXMThZQJDw1TJ4d1Z2Tm4+QTgAQRgYKEi4BWxJfiUVY2wwNw9k7190ktRZRWVgAG0AXTh9erUYF0TPKnaAbhYWUEhYOE1Q3hs7XimsPHwdOWwoKGxEV3Qlgh6dABoqz1Oz8809-DReHbkAN2wRUOAdqkO4YgFQHd5Q8QARsAoB91lAdhgoDh9vEjnB+PZXvIXPQ6PcIMR+Ci6ACIJZgNgFvp0ZjjklzhTzjB8GQMlAAObSHaExBOHYk-hwADecBOi1ycjE8GIDDgAAYhp84BQ4GCtgA6MS8enUyXEADU6pcXL5nlw9nIiwgorliBaxDaI3Jp0uUOWN3luCeIjk1NpDI+lwgH2IoI2Ww+cmx3LgAHoAFRccRgJBwexwMChKCQUiocOhuAAXycVs8mZYmaAA)

Typescript shows that `foo` is of type `T | CSSRule | Node`. However, the typings for `ForEachList` only allow a list of single types, not a union. If I remove the conditions for CSSRule, Attr and Node, it works properly. Why is `foo` not of type `T` here?

Comment: I thought that indexing into the non-generic lists might be the problem, but oddly enough of the item types you get from the non-generic lists `Attr` is missing, so that is not the whole story here...